# Secsh channel 0 open FAILED: open failed: Administratively prohibited ,paramiko.ssh_exception.ChannelException:

Tags: ssh, python

Tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304525/nested-ssh-using-python-paramiko this code and observing issue at vmchannel = vmtransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
as below

Secsh channel 0 open FAILED: open failed: Administratively prohibited
paramiko.ssh_exception.ChannelException: ChannelException(1, 'Administratively prohibited')

i have gone through other docs it says @/etc/ssh/ssh_config file AllowTcpForwarding need to be set to "no" or needs to be commented out but my case its already commented out any idea on what might be causing this